# Why does LOBYTE and HIBYTE cast to DWORD_PTR

Tags: windows, winapi

I was wondering why WinAPI definition HIBYTE and LOBYTE are using DWORD_PTR (4 Bytes - unsigned long) instead of WORD (2 Bytes - unsigned short)

The following definitions are taken from minwindef.h (VS2013) or WinDef.h (VS2008)

```
#define LOBYTE(w) ((BYTE)(((DWORD_PTR)(w)) & 0xff))
#define HIBYTE(w) ((BYTE)((((DWORD_PTR)(w)) >> 8) & 0xff))
```

instead of

```
#define LOBYTE(w) ((BYTE)(((WORD)(w)) & 0xff))
#define HIBYTE(w) ((BYTE)((((WORD)(w)) >> 8) & 0xff))
```

Comment: effect will be the same. faster i be ask why `LOBYTE(w)` not defined as `(BYTE)(w)` - for what need `&0xff` ?

Comment: so why not `#define LOBYTE(w) ((BYTE)(((DWORD_PTR)(w))))
#define HIBYTE(w) ((BYTE)(((DWORD_PTR)(w)) >> 8))` for example ?

Comment: It avoids a compile warning, truncating a 32-bit or 64-bit value to 16 bits is not healthy.  Particularly so on pointer types like LPARAM.

Comment: @HansPassant I agree its not healthy unless you know exactly what you're doing.. but why would the compiler throw a warning on an explicit cast?

Comment: This mattered a lot to programmers that ported their program from 16-bit to 32-bit code 20 years ago.  And again today from 32 to 64-bit code.  [C4311 is a level 1 warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4t91x2k5.aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry for the maybe ignorant question but what's wrong with what RbMm suggested? (BYTE)(w)

Comment: @Tsikon - more exactly `((BYTE)(DWORD_PTR)(w))` and `((BYTE)(((DWORD_PTR)(w)) >> 8))` for avoid warning C4302 when w 64bit pointer. but `&ff` is superfluous

Comment: I wrote some tests to try causing a C4322 warning and rewrote LOBYTE as  #define MYLOBYTE(w) ((BYTE)(((w)) & 0xff)) without success but I did get an error C2296 when passing (DWORD_PTR*) - error C2296: '&' : illegal, left operand has type 'DWORD_PTR *'. Obviously I  cannot use & operator on a pointer.  Could it be the reason for the (DWORD_PTR) cast? to allow pointers to be used with the macro?

Comment: @Tsikon - you need compile x64 code for got warning for truncate pointer.

Comment: @RbMm I did. sizeof(DWORD_PTR) returns 8 and _WIN64 is defined

Comment: what you did exactly ? and are your waring level on maximum ? `(BYTE)(p)` on pointer p give `warning C4302` but `((BYTE)(DWORD_PTR)(p))` and `((BYTE)(((DWORD_PTR)(p)) >> 8))` work ok and correct. so i and ask - for what `&ff` used

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157028/discussion-between-tsikon-and-rbmm).